# Sql Database giving error message while running DBCC CHECKDB()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dbcc

Please assist, While running DBCC checkdb() on my production server I am getting below error.

**Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.**

I also executed Dbcc checkalloc('DBname') with estimateonly
 but that also is giving below message

**Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.**

Then I also executed Dbcc checkalloc('DBname') with no_infomsgs, all_errormsgs
Which also give below error message

Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.

This is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Can someone please assist me in resolving above issue.

Comment: The facf that `DBCC CHECKALLOC` apparently crashes gives credence to the idea that the second cause ("a system table is inconsistent") might be the case. DBCC is good at detecting and repairing problems, but it isn't perfect; some forms of corruption are beyond its capability. The safest thing to do is to restore a backup to a new, fresh machine running SQL Server 2008 R2 and run the check there to ensure there's no hardware issues (or, indeed, a lack of tempdb space, the other possible cause) interfering.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try the same procedure on a newer instance of SQL Server; it might be a DBCC bug that's been fixed (or rather a more robust handling of any corruption that might be there). You're long overdue for an upgrade in any case -- 2008 R2 has been out of extended support for almost a year now.